# How does infinite page scroll affect Alexa ranking?

Tags: ranking, tracking, alexa, page

Alexa says to include their meta tag into site head tags. On infinite scroll pages head tags are included only once.

How does Alexa track pages with infinite scroll? Does that affects site's Alexa ranking?

Comment: First mistake is caring what Alexa ranks your site. Alexa is totally unreliable and certain niches will always be higher due to the fact certain niches have users installing the toolbar more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meta tags are only used to prove you're the owner of the site. It doesn't run any script to keep track of visitors or anything so as long as it's loaded once, it's ok. Alexa site ranking is based on the number of pageviews/visits from people that have the Alexa toolbar installed. An infinite scroll page will probably only count as 1 view.

Alexa rank doesn't mean anything though. If you install the toolbar and visit the site daily, you'll see the rank skyrocketing without any new visits or any real improvement.

Comment: Then infinite scrolling is not beneficial for a high traffic site.

Comment: @busybee235 - No, that isn't what the answer says at all. Infinite scroll is a considered implementation for usability on your website. It has no relevance whatsoever to whether your site receives a lot of traffic or not. I think you may have misunderstood the answer provided.

Comment: Alexa ranks mean nothing. I downloaded the toolbar and all of a sudden my site is the 900th most visited site in Belgium... If you care about it though, you're better off not having an infinite scrolling page. I would just ignore Alexa and find a different way to count visitors.

Comment: @GeoffJackson I got it what you said. Whatever it is, infinite scroll on a page adds only 1 pageview, that affects pageviews/visits.

Comment: @IvoVdv, Now implementing quantcast.